# ip-address sorting is not working in datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I have a datatable in which i am trying to implement ip-address sorting.My javascript code is

```
"aoColumns" :[{"mDataProp": "ipAddr","title":"ipAddr","width":"10%","sType ": "ip-address"}
```

Added js: [ip-address.js](http:////cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.7/sorting/ip-address.js)

But the added plugin ip-address is not detecting in my datatable,because of that sorting is not proper

Comment: "sorting is not proper", could you please explain this little more?

Comment: `"sType "` != `"sType"`

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar ...Here ascending and descending order of ip-address is not correct .For example: In last octect 7 is coming after 10.I think it is using default sorting provided by datatable

Comment: @dandavis  .I have changed "sType " to "sType".But the issue is still there

Comment: Can you reproduce it on jsfiddle?

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar.. I am new to jsfiddle.So that it is not working ,anyway fiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/dxfrca9b/6/)

Comment: You need to add datatable js and css files cdn url  in "External Resources" tab in jsfiddle and select jQuery lib from the dropdown present at upper left corner. Your code is working, just need to remove extra space from `sType` as told by @dandavis. See the working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kawadkarbk31/dxfrca9b/11/)

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar Sorry for adding comment here.It can't be added in your answer because of less reputation to me.I have arranged js as you said

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove extra space for `sType` and rest of your code is working

```
"aoColumns" :[{"mDataProp": "ipAddr","title":"ipAddr","width":"10%","sType": "ip-address"}
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/kawadkarbk31/dxfrca9b/11/)

Comment: Does this ip-address plugin depend on datatable version?

Comment: I don't think so otherwise plugin should have mentioned this. You need to verify that your datatable js must have oSort function. Is this not working in your case?

Comment: If this is not working for you then please check if there are any console log errors.

Comment: oSort is there in my datatable.js.I am using  DataTables 1.10.4

Comment: can you reproduce this issue on jsfiddle?

Comment: I got your problem. While using jquery plugin you need to include dependent jquery files / libs first. In your case `ip-address.js` is depends on  `jquery.dataTables.min.js` hence `jquery.dataTables.min.js` need to include before  `ip-address.js`. Just change the sequence of file and it will work. See [this](https://jsfiddle.net/0s356s68/2/), i have removed `ip-address.js` and added again after `jquery.dataTables.min.js`

Comment: Thanks for your valid suggestions.It is working perfectly in jsfiddle.Unfortunately when applying these to my current project it is not giving desired behaviur.

Comment: have you arrange all your js files in the sequence as suggested by me? please send me your js files with `<script>` in the same sequence as you are using them.

Comment: scripts in my file : '<script src="../js/plugins/dataTables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
 <script src="../js/plugins/dataTables/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
 <script src="../js/plugins/dataTables/dataTables.responsive.js"></script>
 <script src="../js/plugins/dataTables/dataTables.tableTools.min.js"></script>
 <script src="../js/plugins/dataTables/ip-address.js"></script>'

Comment: You need to add jquery library befor datatables js file as shown below  `<script type="text/JavaScript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>`

Comment: I have a common include file in my project that includes jquery.js.

Comment: then there should be some console error on browser. Please use developer tool by pressing F12 (function button) and see console tab.